# Mentioning Users and Self with Discord.PY

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm still really new to coding and the only way I can get this command to work is by doing what I'm doing below. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to write it, but it's not exactly how I want it anyway.

I'm trying to mention the user who uses the command at the beginning and then mention the user that's mentioned within the message. message.author.name is only returning the name of instead of the actual tag of the user that uses the command. Also - I'm not sure if there's an easier way to put the mention first, the only way I could think of doing it is to put a blank space before the mention.

```
elif message.content.startswith('!sayhello'):
    user = message.mentions[0]
    responses = ['' + message.author.name + ' says hello to' + user.mention + '']
    choice = random.choice(responses)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`User.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention) attribute to get a string that will mention the given user.  This applies to the `message.author` as well. If you have multiple messages you're choosing from, it will simplify your code to select the correct template and then fill in the mentions

```
elif message.content.startswith('!sayhello'):
    user = message.mentions[0]
    responses = ["{} says hello to {}", "{} says hi to {}", "{} waves to {}"]
    choice = random.choice(responses)
    choice = choice.format(message.author.mention, user.mention)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, choice)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick! This works a lot better. I do sometimes get an error though, but not always.

    `user = message.mentions[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That will occur if `message` doesn't contain any mentions.